# Communication between two Angular apps

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, web-applications

I just need to achieve this with best practice.  I have two application which is maintaining separate code base and deployed to same server.  Let me name this as App1 and App2.  App1 can be loaded in https://mydomain-dev.com and App2 can be loaded in https://mydomain-dev.com/app2.  The requirement is I want to navigate back and forth between App1 and App2 seamlessly and there will be data communication while doing this navigation as well, say for example userDetails should be shared from App2 to App1 in order make an API call in App1. We checked the localStorage option to do this but I do not want to put everything in local storage and access it from there  every time.

Is there a best way to achieve this, and remember the apps has a separate code base

I have something in my mind like exporting App2 as a module and consume that and yes still not sure if it feasible and best approach

Comment: have u tried using url `parameters` ?

Comment: No, not sure if it feasible to handle complex JSON data which we may have to pass from one app to other

Comment: were you able to achieve this? I have the same requirement.

Comment: We used local storage for now and achieved this.

Comment: yeah i guess so, if u need some amount of data u need json which u cant use parameters to do that, hope someday u find the best practices for this and pls post it to the answer, hope it'll help someone in the future

Comment: I have the exact requirement, till date are you still using local storage, or found another better alternative?